# what is the difference between sortBy - sortedBy and sortWith - sortedWith in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm just exploring kotlin collection and I observed one important behavior.

```
val sports = listOf<Sports>(
        Sports("cricket", "7"),
        Sports("gilli", "10"),
        Sports("lagori", "8"),
        Sports("goli", "6"),
        Sports("dabba", "4")
    )

    sports.sortedBy { it.rating } // sortedByDescending is to sort in descending
        .forEach({ println("${it.name} ${it.rating}") })


}

class Sports(name: String, rating: String) {
    var name: String = name
    var rating: String = rating
}
```

above I can only get `sortedBy` method i.e which starts with `sorted`. I don't know why I'm not getting `sortBy` and `sortWith` operations.

can anyone give explanation for this in simple words.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The first point, There are two list types. `listOf` and `mutableListOf`.

So, if you need `sortBy`, `sortWith` or anything which starts with `sort...` then you must use `mutableListOf`.

- `sort...` will be applied to the original list. but not return anything.
- `sorted...` will not change the original list but returns a new list after applying changes.

If you want to keep the original list of elements unchanged go with `sorted` stuff else please choose `sort` stuff.

Comment: That's a general pattern in the Kotlin stdlib: `<verb>()` methods modify the object, while `<verb>ed()` methods return a new object instead.

Comment: @gidds well that's informative. I don't find any tutorial

Comment: What @gidds said also applies to Python, not relevant but it's a handy mnemonic for me.

Answer (score 6):

### sortBy (Just sort the elements inside the list) -> Used on MutableList

```
 /**
     * Sorts elements in the list in-place according to natural sort order of the value returned by specified [selector] function.
     * 
     * The sort is _stable_. It means that equal elements preserve their order relative to each other after sorting.
     */
    public inline fun <T, R : Comparable<R>> MutableList<T>.sortBy(crossinline selector: (T) -> R?): Unit {
        if (size > 1) sortWith(compareBy(selector))
    }
```

### sortedBy (Returns a new list with its elements sorted) -> Used on List

```
/**
 * Returns a list of all elements sorted according to natural sort order of the value returned by specified [selector] function.
 * 
 * The sort is _stable_. It means that equal elements preserve their order relative to each other after sorting.
 */
public inline fun <T, R : Comparable<R>> Iterable<T>.sortedBy(crossinline selector: (T) -> R?): List<T> {
    return sortedWith(compareBy(selector))
}
```