# What is difference between sortedBy() and sortedWith(...)?

Tags: kotlin

I am unable to understand the difference between 2 sortedBy and sortedWith and when to use anyone from them. Please explain.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what is the difference between sortBy - sortedBy and sortWith - sortedWith in kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61208049/what-is-the-difference-between-sortby-sortedby-and-sortwith-sortedwith-in-ko)

Comment: no that explains only between sortWith and sortedWith not in between sortedBy and sortedWith

Comment: [sortedBy](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted-by.html),  [sortedWith](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted-with.html)

Comment: but we can use custom Comparator in both...

Comment: no, only in `sortedWith`, `sortedBy` uses selector function

Comment: so how do they differ?

Comment: `sortedBy` allows you to very easily sort by some property of the object type. Like if you wanted to sort a `Person` class by its `age` property. `sortedWith` is for using a Comparator, which allows more complicated comparisons. For example, maybe you want to sort your People by their home country, followed by their name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sortedBy` only takes in a selector function as mentioned in the documentation:

```
inline fun <T, R : Comparable<R>> Array<out T>.sortedBy(
    crossinline selector: (T) -> R?
): List<T>
```

Example:

```
val myList: List<Int> = listOf(1,3,4,5,7,24,5)
print(myList.sortedBy {it}) // outputs [1, 3, 4, 5, 5, 7, 24]
```

Whereas `sortedWith` takes in a Comparator:

```
fun <T> Sequence<T>.sortedWith(
    comparator: Comparator<in T>
): Sequence<T>
```

Example:

```
val myList: List<Int> = listOf(1,3,4,5,7,24,5)
print(myList.sortedWith (Comparator<Int>{ a, b ->
    when {
        a > b -> 1
        a < b -> -1
        else -> 0
    }
}))
```

Its similar to `Comparable` vs `Comparator` in java

Hope this helps !!

Comment: So which one is faster? Like both methods can serve the purpose so which one to choose to increase efficiency and memory management?

Comment: There are difference in scenarios for which these will be used. Let's say you want to compare an object with another to perform your sorting in some custom way, then you need to use a comparator.